# Membership and asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I’m building a site that needs users created with different roles and permissions to access different areas of the site.

I using mvc 2 but I can’t find much clear guidance on using the Membership tool with mvc to create accounts and roles etc.

I tried the web configuration tool which works but I would like to administrate the site remotely.

I used the aspnet_regsql tool so I can access the SqlMembershipProvider Schema in my Database.

I also need to add more information to a user like profile info and a picture, would I add these to the membership tables or create separate tables for this?

Any advice or help would be really helpful?

Thanks

Jemes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always found that it is better to create your own membership provider rather than use the default ASP.NET MVC membership service that you get for free with the regsql tool. Don't be afraid to open up the Account Membership Service (the descendant of IMembershipService) and start playing around with it.

The first thing I do when starting a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project is to gut the account classes down to a simple provider and use my own Users table in my SQL Server database.

Since the membership service implements the IMembershipService interface, it will be easy for you to start over using your own business object framework and implement the interface.

Get your Users working first. Then come back and create your roles tables once you have your Users working and logging in.

Comment: If I create my own provider will features like Authorise still work on my controllers?

Comment: @Jemes Absolutely. By creating your own you are really just telling the provider where to look to get your user. You just tell it to look at your Users table instead of what the default project provides you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What do mean by 'gut the account classes down to a simple provider'?

Comment: @Jemes Sure. I can tell you how I do it. I open Models\AccountModels and separate each of the classes into their own file. Most of them are just view models anyway. Then you can re implement IMembershipService on AccountMembershipService to use your own business layer (linq to sql, entity framework) and probably a repository pattern to load the database records. You might not even need to change the FormsAuthenticationService. Then your AccountController will change a bit to use your own business layer but the compiler should point you to those spots.

Comment: I new to .net and MVC so havent come across the membership before. I like the idea of creating my own provider as then I know whats going on but will I be creating more work for my self?

Comment: If you use anything beyond what the regsql tool provides you for a user, you are creating more work for yourself if you don't write your own.

Comment: Sorry to ask so many questions. I don't think I'm going to use any more features then the membership provider builds in. I've created a class and inherited the mebership provider and abstracted a class so all the method are created for me. Is this where you just create all these methods yourself?

Comment: Yes. Once you have a class that implements the membership service interface just  implement each method it requires. If you get stuck you can look back at the default template's membership service to see how they do it. There should be plenty of examples online of how to implement your own if you get stuck though.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same mechanism as in asp.net.
https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx
http://netrsc.blogspot.com/2009/04/membership-management-for-aspnet-mvc.html

Whenever I need some more info about user I create my own profile info table. Do not change the generated membership tables because of upgrades.

Comment: Do you use the built in membership system or did you create your own provider?

Comment: Always the built in membership. Generally I think that there are situations when you use your own but it's not very often. Maybe some larger or more special projects. Consider the maintainability. swhook is right that it isn't especially difficult but it's IMHO very often an excessive work.

Comment: Well if you would like to create your own provider you should be able to identify what more it brings you. If nothing or you don't know, just stick with the built in membership.

Comment: Easy and very nice tutorials on this http://www.asp.net/learn/security/?lang=cs with Storing Additional User Information. (Hope this the last of my comment monologue :-)

Comment: With the Built In Membership, I will still need to have create my functions to create, edit users etc. The membership just gives me the database schema does'nt it?

Comment: Yes. The built in ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool (WSAT) is useless in the production. The Membership cares for things like [Authorize(Roles="Administrator")] on Action and you don't have to solve the complete process on your own. But you have to write the complete administration backend. There was a project ASP.NET WSAT but it was abandoned http://forums.asp.net/t/1390061.aspx At least good to peak how it should look like. But if you follow the links I gave you above you will be able to build the administration. When you get to used to how the things work it's really not difficult.

Comment: If you want to become a real Pro :-) you can buy the book http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0764596985.html

Answer (score 0):

The [MembershipStarterKit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit) project might be of use.